# In Flutter how can I remove a part of a widget. I want to remove bottom half of the container widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am trying to render something like this :

[the image I am trying to render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1qSp.png)

So far using this code :

```
Stack(
            fit: StackFit.loose,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment:
                MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                      width: 110,
                      height: 110,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/profile.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 70.0, ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ClipRect(

                        child: Container(
                          color:Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
                          width: 110,
                          height: 60,
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.camera_alt,
                            color: Colors.grey[800],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
            ])
```

I have got this image :
[Image I got rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r67xa.png)

Now my googling led me to believe that ClipRect can be a solution here but I am not able to find the exact solution, So I am thinking all I need to do is to cut the part of the rectangular container that is going outside of the circular avatar but I am not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Try this layout:

```
ClipOval
  Stack: alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    Container: width: 110, height: 110
    Positioned: bottom: 0, child: Container(width: 110, height: 40)
    Icon
```

[UPDATED]

use ClipRRect with radius instead of ClipOval

OR

use [flutter_custom_clippers](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers), OvalBottomBorderClipper() for the lower part of container.

Comment: Its not working, its rendering exactly the same as I was rendering it before, its not cutting off the part which is going out of the circle